# Closing single JFrame not working bug

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I decided to put "close" buttons on my JFrames. If I test just that JFrame by itself, it works fine, but when I try to close it after opening it through another class, it won't close.

Here is the code:

```
JButton btnClose = new JButton("Close");
btnClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        frame.dispose();
    }
});
btnClose.setBounds(282, 666, 96, 50);
contentPane.add(btnClose);
```

I have tried using `frame.dispose()` and `frame.close()` and `super.dispose()` but the only one that works is `system.exit(0);` but then that exits the whole program.

The issue:

- If I test the `JFrame` by itself, the frame closes fine.
- If I open the program and navigate to that specific `JFrame`, the close button does nothing.

Please advise.

Comment: "when I try to close it after opening it through another class,"- post code for this part

Comment: Have you check if the execution arrive to that point of code?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). *"..that specific `JFrame`.."*  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: Yoy can try using `JFrame.this.dispose();`

Comment: @Rajesh I am opening the JFrame from a class using the .visible(true);. then the class shows and that is it.

Comment: post the full code please for investigation

Answer (score 1):

Did you add a display statement in the ActionListener to make sure the code is being executed?

If the code is being executed, then the problem is probably that the frame variable has in invalid reference.

You don't need to keep a reference to the frame. Instead use something like:

```
Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( e.getSource() );
window.dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setVisible(false);` on the frame. Then call dispose.